# Can we write the mass $M$, a Casimir invariant of the Galilean group, as a function of its generators?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, galilean-relativity, invariants

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Galilean_group), the mass $M$ is one of the Casimir invariants of the Galilean group. Casimir invariants of a group are made out of the generators, and they commute with all the generators of the group. For example, the Casimir invariant of the group $SU(2)$ is $J^2$ which is made out of $J_1, J_2, J_3$ as $$J^2:=J_1^2+J_2^2+J_3^2.\tag{1}$$ Another example is a Casimir invariant of the Poincare group $P^\mu P_\mu$ which is made out of $P_0, P_1,P_2, P_2$ as $$P^\mu P_\mu:=-P_0^2+P_1^2+P_2^2+P_3^2.\tag{2}$$

In the same manner, can we write $M$ as a function of the generators Galilean group?

Comment: It is not qudratic.

Comment: @DanielC Can you elaborate? I am asking how to write M using the generators of the Galilean group.

Comment: See also this and links within: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103441/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *No,* the mass operator $M$ is the [central charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_charge) operator in the [central extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Central_extension) [known as the Bargmann algebra (BA)] of the [Galilean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Galilean_group) (GA).
2. In other words, the mass operator $M$ is by definition *not* part of the GA. [The momenta and Galilean boosts [commute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation#Galilean_group) by definition within the GA.]
3. If we define a [Casimir invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element) of a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) as a central element of its [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) (UEA), then the mass operator $M$ is a Casimir invariant for the BA but *not* for the GA.

   See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103441/2451) related Phys.SE post.
4. The above bolsters the following point:

   > *The natural non-relativistic Lie algebra in Newtonian mechanics is the BA, not the GA!*